# Jersey: Consume all POST data into one object

Tags: java, rest, jersey, unmarshalling

I am using Jersey 1.8 in my application. I am trying to consume `POST` data at the server. The data is of the type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. **Is there a method to get all the data in one object, maybe a `Map<String, Object>`.**

I ran into Jersey's `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)`. But using this would require me to use `@FormParam`, which can be tedious if the number of parameters are huge. Or maybe one way is this:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/urienodedeample")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response uriEncodedExample(String uriInfo){
        logger.info(uriInfo);
        //process data
        return Response.status(200).build();
    }
```

The above code consumes and presents the form data in a `String` object.

```
_search=false&nd=1373722302667&rows=10&page=1&sidx=email&sord=desc
```

Processing this can be error prone as any misplaced `&` and split() will return corrupt data.

I used UriInfo for most of my work which would give me the query parameters in a `MultiValuedMap` or for other POST requests, sent the payload in `json` format which would in turn be unmarshalled into a `Map<String, Object>`. Any suggestions on how I can do the same if the POST data is of the type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Got it. As per [this](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e4588) document, I can use a `MultivaluedMap<K,V>` or [Form](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Form.html) to get all the POST data of the type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in one object. A working exmple:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/urienodedeample")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response uriEncodedExample(MultivaluedMap<String,String> multivaluedMap) {
        logger.info(multivaluedMap);
        return Response.status(200).build();
    }
```

Comment: You can also use MultivaluedHashMap

Answer (score 0):

For cases where the `Content-Type` is `multipart/form-data`, this `MultivaluedMap` approach won't work.

Use `FormDataMultiPart` - [docs here](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/FormDataMultiPart.html).