# Retrieving all POST data parameters into map with Java Jersey

Tags: java, http, post, jersey

I'm trying to gather all parameters of an HTTP POST request into a map, however it's not working.

With a GET, I used:

```
@Context
private HttpServletRequest request;
```

and

```
@GET
@Path("/{uuid}/invoke/{method}")
public Response invokeMethod (
    @PathParam("uuid") String uuid,
    @PathParam("method") String methodz
) {
    Map<String, String[]> params = request.getParameterMap();
```

and it returned the map. However, when sending form data via a POST instead of inline with the URL, the map is being returned as NULL.

Is there a similar way to retrieve all the parameters at once using a POST?

EDIT:

My data is being submitted as a serialized JSON, so using a cURL statement as an example:

```
curl --data "firstname=john&lastname=smith" http://localhost:8080/uuid1/apitest/method1
```

Ideally, I'd want to get a hashmap of something like:

```
ParamMap["firstname"] = "john"
ParamMap["lastname"] = "smith"
```

Also, the parameters won't be static, so this cURL:

```
curl --data "job=construction" http://localhost:8080/uuid2/apitest/method2
```

would result in:

```
ParamMap["job"] = "construction"
```

Comment: How is your request coming?

Comment: Edited my question with how my data will be coming in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got this resolved using this thread:

[Jersey: Consume all POST data into one object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630788/jersey-consume-all-post-data-into-one-object)

My new function is:

```
@POST
@Path("/{uuid}/invoke/{method}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response invokeMethod (
    MultivaluedMap<String,String> params,
    @PathParam("uuid") String uuid,
    @PathParam("method") String method
) {
```

Variable 'params' is now a map containing form data key/value pairs.

Answer (score -1):

You can try following code

```
@POST
@Path("/{uuid}/invoke/{method}")
public Response invokeMethod (
    @Context UriInfo request
) {
    Map<String, List<String>> params = request.getPathParameters();
  }
```

You no need to write

```
 @Context
 private HttpServletRequest request;
```

Now You can get idea...

Comment: This would just get parameters set within the URI, not the actual POST data in the body. I've updated my question with how I'd be submitting the HTTP request to give you a better idea of what I'm looking for.